# AJAX post request returns same response for different requests

Tags: ajax, caching, paypal, payment

While using paypal checkout i encounter issue that later on results in same payment even for two different users.

It happens during the create-payment flow.

My paypal checkout setup:

```
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });


 paypal.Button.render({
     env: 'production',
     locale: 'en_US',
     style: {
         color: 'silver',
         size: 'medium',
         label: 'checkout',
         shape: 'rect',
         layout: 'vertical',
     },

     payment: (data, actions) => {
         return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             $.ajax({
                 url: '/p/create-payment/',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 data: {
                     body: body
                 },
                 method: 'POST',
                 headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token': '{{csrfToken}}' }
            })
           .done(( data ) => {
               resolve(data.id)
               reject("")
            })
        })
    },

    onAuthorize: (data, actions) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/p/execute-payment/',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    paymentID: data.paymentID,
                    payerID:   data.payerID,
                    body: body,
                },
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token': '{{csrfToken}}' }
            })
            .done(( data ) => {
                if(data.status === 'success') {
                    resolve(window.open('success',"_self"))
                }else if(data.status === 'pending'){
                    resolve(window.open('pending, "_self"))
                } else reject(window.open('failure', "_self"))
            })
        })
    },

    onError:  (err) => {
        window.open('paymentFailure', "_self");
        console.error(err)
    }

}, '#paypal-button');
```

First Atttempt:
I go to my page and open the paypal checkout, the person that should receive the payment is corrent, amount and everything else as well, the request itself takes around 3-4 seconds

Second Attempt:
When opening the page second time i click the checkout button and this time the request takes 0.2-0.4 second and the data is exactly the same as in the first created payment, even the PAY-ID from paypal is the same

I can log the data returned from ajax request to /p/create-payment creating the payment first time works fine as said above, but the second one i see exactly the same data as from the first time.

I would like to note that i have logs on my server, and **they do not show during the second payment creation process** as if it doesn't requests and its instantly done.

Here are screenshots of the request:
[image: The first correct payment created]

[image: Possibly cached request of the second payment being created]

I have been also trying to clear cache/cookies of my browser but this doesn't solve the issue. The users can be on two different devices and this issue still happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res.header("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
res.header("Pragma", "no-cache")
res.header("Expires", "0")
```

Ser the data is being cached so uncaching it is the solution.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue, wouldn't think that node route would cache the response

Comment: I'm kinda new to HTTP concept. Should I set this one the client side's request or server side's response?

Comment: res.setHeader() is a native method of Node.js and res.header() is an alias of res.set() method from Express framework.